# SQL: Utilizing criteria table with different types of criteria applied to different fields

Tags: sql, postgresql, criteria

I'm looking on how to provide permissions to users where I have a criteria table that has field/value pairs that match to different fields in my dataset.

Below is the permissions table.

| Field | Value | Permissioned user |
| --- | --- | --- |
| region | AMER | Kim |
| manager | Chris | Kim |
| division | Sales | Kim |
| region | EMEA | Julie |
| manager | Jim | Julie |

This is the format of the data.  Different fields represent the different fields above.  There can be 8 or more different fields (eg region, business unit, dept head, etc) so I need an approach that scales beyond my dummy dataset.

| EMP ID | region | division | manager |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AMER | Marketing | Chris |
| 2 | AMER | Sales | Chris |
| 3 | EMEA | Sales | Chris |
| 4 | AMER | Sales | Jim |
| 5 | EMEA | Marketing | Jim |
| 6 | EMEA | Sales | Jim |

The desired output applies the criteria across the different fields.

| Permisioned User | EMP ID | region | division | manager |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Kim | 2 | AMER | Sales | Chris |
| Julie | 5 | EMEA | Marketing | Jim |
| Julie | 6 | EMEA | Sales | Jim |

I'm not really sure where to begin as I can't seem to get close.  Intersect means that I always have the same fields applied in criteria but this isn't the case. Plus different users can have different number of criteria rules.  Any help is really appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the exhaustive list of fields that may be used to define permissions is fixed, then you can create a static query. If the list of fields is not fixed and only known at the run time, then you need a dynamic query.

**Static list of permission fields / Static query**

We cross join the `permissions` and `data` tables.
Then, we group the rows by `"Permissioned user"` and `"EMP ID"`, and we only keep the grouped rows which all satisfy the (field, value) correspondance thanks to the aggregate function `bool_and` in the `HAVING` clause.
Finally we add all the columns of the data table and we order by *"EMP ID"* :

```
WITH list AS
(
SELECT p."Permissioned user"
     , d."EMP ID"
  FROM data AS d
 CROSS JOIN permissions AS p
 GROUP BY p."Permissioned user", d."EMP ID"
HAVING bool_and( CASE 
                   WHEN p.field = 'region' THEN p.value = d.region
                   WHEN p.field = 'manager' THEN p.value = d.manager
                   WHEN p.field = 'division' THEN p.value = d.division
                   WHEN [...]  -- insert here the rest of the fields list
                   ELSE FALSE
                 END
               )
)
SELECT l."Permissioned user", d.*
  FROM list AS l
 INNER JOIN data AS d
    ON d."EMP ID" = l."EMP ID"
 ORDER BY d."EMP ID" ;
```

**Variable list of permission fields / Dynamic query**

The dynamic query allows to search data according to criteria which are known only at the run time. It must be embedded in a plpgsql function which will return the result of the dynamic query. For each "Permissioned user" in table `permissions`, the principle is to generate the *where_clause* string which matches with the `WHERE` clause of the query searching in table `data`. The *"Permissioned user"* and the *where_clause* are passed to the plpgsql function `permissioned_user` which contains the dynamic query and returns the list of *"EMP ID"* in table `data` :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION permissioned_user 
( INOUT "Permissioned user" text
, IN where_clause text
, OUT "EMP ID" integer
)
RETURNS setof record LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE AS
$$
BEGIN  
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE E'
    SELECT ' || quote_nullable("Permissioned user") || E'
         , "EMP ID"
      FROM data AS d
     WHERE ' || where_clause ;
END ;
$$
```

Then the following query returns the expected result. First it generates the where_clause string associated to every "Permissioned user" in table `permissions`. Then it call the `function permissioned_user()`, gets the *"EMP ID"* list and joins with the rest of the `data` columns :

```
WITH list AS
(   SELECT "Permissioned user"
         , string_agg('d.' || quote_ident(Field) || E' = \'' || quote_nullable(Value) || E'\'', ' AND ') AS where_clause
      FROM permissions
     GROUP BY "Permissioned user"
)
SELECT a."Permissioned user", d.*
  FROM list AS l
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL permissioned_user(l."Permissioned user", l.where_clause) AS a
 INNER JOIN data AS d
    ON d."EMP ID" = a."EMP ID"
  ORDER BY a."EMP ID"
```

Note that any *Field* value in table `permissions` which doesn't correspond to a column name in the `data` table will generate a SQL ERROR.

Comment: Great explanation!  As a moderate level SQL user, I don't feel as bad about being stuck now :)